# Adding dates in java without the use of built in date or calender features

Tags: java, date

So in class we have been tasked with manipulating dates in java. However we are not allowed to use any of the built in java date or calender features so I am a bit of a loss. I understand the logic behind it but cant figure out how to turn it into code. for example the base date is january 1 2001. So in code something like

```
int month = 1;  
int day = 1;
int year = 2001;
```

I need to add 40 days to this. Since Jan has 31 days in it that of course would be taken into account. I also have these strings to make things simple

```
String sMonths[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
int numDays[] = {31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};
int numMonths[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
```

Im kind of lost at this point. Any nudge in the right direction would be a massive help

Comment: Do you also need to handle leap years? And do you have to be even slightly efficient?

Comment: It would help to cover leap years which you can do with multiple moduluses however it does not need to be efficient

Comment: Right. Well I'd start off with a class representing a date - do you have that yet? I'd recommend making it immutable (for the sake of sanity). It's hard to really give a hint about where to go without giving it all away... but you could think about having a notional "day" that can be invalid - and then you keep adjusting the year/month (and update day) until it *is* valid. (So if the day is greater than the number of days in the current month, increment the month and decrement the day by the number of days in that month... then repeat.)

Comment: It may be useful to encapsulate the two things you need to be aware of when incrementing/decrementing days into utility methods: `int getDaysInMonth(int month)` and `boolean isLeapYear(int year)`.